# Можно ли в Python сделать так, чтобы цикл while прерывался КАК ТОЛЬКО условие выполнения становится ложным?

Tags: python, циклы, while

Возьмём для примера код:

```
i = 0
while i < 13:
   i += 1; print(i)
   i += 2; print(i)
   i += 3; print(i)
```

Если мы его запустим, получим это:

```
1
3
6
7
9
12
13
15
18
```

Хотя во время выполнения цикла while i становится равным 13, цикл сразу после этого не прекращается. А можно этого как-то избежать? Чтобы на i = 13 цикл прервался.

Comment: нет . . . . . .

Comment: только дополнительные ифы вставлять

Answer (score -2):

И не равен 13
while(i<13 and i != 13):

Comment: Если Вы внимательно проанализируете код в вопросе, то заметите, что `i` никогда не будет равно `13` во время проверки условия цикла.